# Why can't I assign a string of numbers as a key in a javascript object?

Tags: javascript

This is done in the node shell:

```
> results = []
[]
> num = 5
5
> results[num] = []
[]
> results
[ , , , , , [] ]
>
```

And even if I try to stringify the number:

```
> results = []
[]
> num = 5
5
> results[num.toString()] = []
[]
> results
[ , , , , , [] ]
> results['5'] = []
[]
> results
[ , , , , , [] ]
>
```

It would seem that javascript is interpreting a string as a number in the definition of an object?

I'd like the results to look like this:

```
results = [ { '5' : [
                   { key : value },
                   { key2 : value }
                  ]
            }
          ]
```

Comment: You can do that, what's wrong with your example? Only you can't expect to get an array with objects consisting of one array when assigning an empty array to an index of an empty array

Comment: See [JavaScript "Associative Arrays" Considered Harmful](http://andrewdupont.net/2006/05/18/javascript-associative-arrays-considered-harmful/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not working with just any kind of object.  `[]` is an Array, and has certain magical properties -- one of them being that non-negative integer-looking keys extend the array.  Even if they're strings, that doesn't matter -- all object keys are strings anyway, and arrays are still objects.

Try using `{}` rather than `[]` if you don't want arrays' special treatment of integer-looking keys.

```
> results = {}
{}
> results[5] = []
[]
> results
{ '5': [] }
```

Course, if you're looking to make the value a bunch of key/value pairs as well, you might consider saying `results[5] = {}`.

```
> results = {}
{}
> results[5] = {}
{}
> results[5]['key'] = 'value'
'value'
> results
{ '5': { key: 'value' } }
> results[5]['key2'] = 'value'
'value'
> results
{ '5': { key: 'value', key2: 'value' } }
```

The `[]`s you're asking for seem kinda broken in most cases.  Javascript objects are by their very nature dictionaries, and having a list of them with one key/value pair each seems to add complexity without real gain.  The exception would be if you want to have a bunch of values per key *and* are willing to put up with the added ugliness of having to loop through the whole list of pairs each time you want to find something.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. Not sure why the original question was down voted... new to the language is all.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you would achieve the desired structure, though I'm sure you could probably find an easier way to represent this data.

```
var results = [];
results.push({
    '5': []
});
results[0]['5'].push({
    key: value
});
results[0]['5'].push({
    key2: value2
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jumY2/

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working as written but is missing your intended functionality because you are trying to set an array index to a value instead of using a non-array javascript object.. see below for an example

```
results = [];
results[0] = { '5': [ { /* ... * / } ] };
```

this would result in

```
[ { '5':  [ {} ] } ]
```

Answer (score 1):

That's how arrays work. The length of an array is determined by its highest index. If you assign a value to the fifth position, the array length is 6.

The output you see (i.e. `[ , , , , , [] ]`) is only how the console outputs the array.

It will still have only one element assigned, which you can see if you do `console.dir(results)`.

Having sparse arrays like this is perfectly fine, though if you actually want something like a hashmap, you should use an object instead of an array.

---

**Note:** All properties (also array indexes, because arrays are just special objects) are converted to strings, so there is really no difference between `results[5]` and `results['5']`.